# Methods for filtering position signal

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, regularization, filtrations

I'm working on a location detection algorithm. This is my outcome - postion:

[image: x(t)]

Here's first derivative after time - velocity:

[[image: vx(t)]]

My goal is to apply some filtration to the signal for smoothing the waveforms. I'm searching for a method of filtration that can work in real-time applications.

I need to smooth the waveforms because of the next step which is synthesis of the PID algorithm. These "peaks" in velocity are too big. I tried simple Kalman Filter but it doesn't give the expected results.

First trajectories x(t) will be linear, next I would like to study some non-linear trajectories of x(t). Algorithm for filtration should work for both cases.

I am looking for ideas, what filtering algorithms can I apply? I heard about EKF, and average based methods (moving average etc.).

Thank You all in advance for Your help. I'm new here :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. There exist very many methods to smooth functions/signals. Maybe someone voted down because the question is very generic and usually specific questions are encouraged. Also please try to add more useful tags to the question I will try to add some as help.

Comment: This is a broad engineering question about signal processing. Have you tried basic low pass filters, etc? You are essentially asking for free consulting.

Comment: Thx for commenting. I'm a newbie here :)

Comment: I don't need any help with implementation of filter, I'm just looking for just for ideas. Maybe someone will suggest some nonconventional technique that I'm aware of.  I will try low pass filter, thx for idea :) I tried with moving average but it didn't work properly.